# Can you put Silverlight app into Kiosk mode?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

Is it possible to tell an out-of-browser `Silverlight` app to run in `kiosk mode`?

I can set it to full screen, but can we disable keystrokes that would allow a user with a keyboard to interact with Windows i.e. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> etc.?

This is for an app that will run in full screen on a touchscreen tablet, most of the time there won't be a keyboard on-screen, but there is a `Connect to Facebook` function that will pop-up a keyboard for them to use to log-in.

Comment: Have a look these sites,some tablets supports SL I think,Beside this there was a tech. "microsoft surface" could be another alternative maybe,http://www.silverlighthack.com/post/2008/07/22/Silverlight-and-(Multi)-Touch-Tablets.aspx http://michaelcrump.net/who-says-silverlight-can-t-run-on-a-tablet

Comment: Hi David, I'm actually tied in to the tablet I have to use (it's a Win 7 Acer). It's not something I have control over. I was just wondering if there was a setting for OOB apps for "kiosk mode" much the same way you can enter fullscreen i.e. "Application.Host.Current.IsKiosk = true".

Comment: I don't think there is a native way.If the project is not too complex you may solve by refactoring.Code a Class derived on TextBox such as    KioskTextBox:TextBox{//TODO ?} .Also you may have a look here http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/htmlplaceholder/silverlight-4-kiosk-application-oob.aspx . The final and the worst thing is using osk.exe in Win7 :)

Comment: At the moment are using OSK and, yea, it isn't nice! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install your application as a trusted Silverlight application. See reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189023(v=vs.95).aspx

### Full-Screen Mode with Trusted Applications

The full-screen message, user-initiation requirement, keyboard restrictions, and dialog-box restrictions do not apply to trusted applications. Additionally, trusted applications do not display the user-consent dialog box when using the StaysFullScreenWhenUnfocused setting.

In trusted applications, you can enter full-screen mode in a Application.Startup or FrameworkElement.Loaded event handler. However, you must do so by setting the IsFullScreen property in a delegate passed to the Dispatcher.BeginInvoke method.

Because the ESC key has no built-in effect for trusted applications, you can use it for your own purposes. In this case, you should implement and document an alternative so that users can exit full-screen mode.